# Does a function defined inside another function gets redefined throughout the while-loop?

Tags: python, function

The code:

```
def useful_function():
    def multiply(a, b):
        return a * b
    return multiply(2, 2)

while True:
    print(useful_function())
```

Does the fact that the `multiply` function is defined inside `useful_function` mean that each time the while-loop works, the `multiply` function is redefined?

Comment: Yes, it initializes on ram again and again but it won't cause performace issues in this shape don't worry

Comment: @cesebe27
why not?

Comment: it's really short and easy funtion

Comment: This is obviously a simplified example - you could remove the function and use `return 4` instead - so I am not sure "it won't cause performance issues ... because its really short and easy" is a valid argument ...